# TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 'x'

Tags: python, torchvision

Can somebody tell, please, what's wrong? I'm really don't understand (MLP and CNN models). MLP works correctly, I've this problem only with CNN. Tried to find something there but all without any result

My CNN model:

```
class CNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(CNN, self).__init__()
    
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=1, out_channels=64, kernel_size=4, padding=2)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=4, padding=2)
        self.conv3 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=64, kernel_size=4)
        self.conv4 = nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=4)

        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128 * 4 * 4, 256)  
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(256, 256)  
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(256, 10)

        self.drop = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)
        self.pool = nn.MaxPool2d(kernel_size=2, stride=2)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = F.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv2(x)))
        x = self.drop(x)
        x = F.relu(self.conv3(x))
        x = self.pool(F.relu(self.conv4(x)))
        x = self.drop(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 128 * 4 * 4)
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x
```

Code with error:

```
 conv_net_4 = CNN() ## right there I need to put something, but don't know, what exactly
 loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
 learning_rate = 1e-4
 optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(conv_net_4.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)

 losses_4 = fit(conv_net_4, optimizer, loss_fn, 4)

 plt.plot(losses_4)
 plt.ylabel('Loss')
 plt.show()

 correct_4 = test_report(conv_net_4)
 print('Accuracy: %.2f %%' % ((np.array(correct_4)).mean()))



Traceback (here for more uderstanding):

         TypeError                                 Traceback (most 
     recent call last)
         <ipython-input-62-1091c742672c> in <module>
         ----> 1 conv_net_4 = CNN()
               2 loss_fn = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
               3 learning_rate = 1e-4
               4 optimizer = 
     torch.optim.Adam(conv_net_4.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
               5 
    
          /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist- 
    packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py in _call_impl(self, *input, 
     **kwargs)
            1192         if not (self._backward_hooks or 
     self._forward_hooks or self._forward_pre_hooks or 
     _global_backward_hooks
            1193                 or _global_forward_hooks or 
     _global_forward_pre_hooks):
         -> 1194             return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
            1195         # Do not call functions when jit is used
            1196         full_backward_hooks, non_full_backward_hooks 
     = [], []
    
         TypeError: forward() missing 1 required positional argument: 
     'x'
```

Probably problem with something in other pieces of code?

Comment: Please show the full traceback. There's no call to `forward()` in the code you posted.